# How do I reset a locked Apple Watch in Airplane Mode?

Tags: security, password, apple-watch, airplane-mode, apple-watch.app

Through a series of events the passcode entries on an Apple Watch has been exhausted and the watch is locked with this message:

> Wrong Passcode
>
> Open the Apple Watch app on your iPhone, go to
>   Passcode, then tap Re-enable Passcode Entry to try again.

But when I go to Passcode on the Apple Watch app it just spins probably because the watch is in Airplane Mode.

When I try to reset the watch through the Apple Watch app I get this error message:

> Could Not Connect to Apple Watch
>
> Make sure your Apple Watch is nearby, powered on, and not in Airplane
>   Mode.

But I can't turn off Airplane mode on the watch because it locked. Do I have any other options besides taking to the Apple store with proof of purchase?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks like there is a way to erase a locked Apple Watch.

1. Hold down the side button to see the options to power off the watch.
2. Force touch
3. Select 'Erase all content and settings'

I discovered you can force touch on the power off screen from this site:
http://www.barryschiffer.com/how-to-recover-an-apple-watch-stuck-in-a-crash-reboot-loop/

Official link - https://support.apple.com/en-in/HT204567

If this fails, service from Apple can restore and reset devices that are non responsive or even need hardware intervention or repair.

Comment: Are you sure? I don't see any "Erase All Contents And Settings" option on my Apple Watch.

Comment: Yeah, looks just like it does on the linked website.